# How do I change 'AM' to 'PM' in a Date Object JAVA

Tags: java, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

I am trying to use Date objects and calculate time differences for an android app. But I face a problem when time is in '12:00'. I mean when I input date as 12:12:00 Java AM/PM formatter returns 12:12:00AM but it should be 12:12:00PM.

I can't find any way to solve it.

```
Date date = new Date(); 
String stringDate = "2019-09-13 12:12:00";  
SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");  
Date date6 = formatter6.parse(stringDate);   
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date6));
```

It returns 12:12:00 AM
but it should be 12:12:00 PM for correct calculations

Comment: Does changing `hh` to `HH` make any difference?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); ` .

Comment: Use `java.time`, especially the classes `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime` along with `DateTimeFormatter`. That's the modern way…

Comment: Do _not_ use SimpleDateFormat  or recommend it

Comment: So should `pm` be the standard for all times that don't define whether it's am or pm? If not, how should the parser figure out which one it should be?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Line:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

The `hh` makes sure that hours are parsed as AM/PM values b/w 1-12. To get the desired result, you can use `HH` marker which parses hour values between 0-23. So, the code should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDateTime`

```
String stringDate = "2019-09-13 12:12:00";  
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, formatter);
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(formatter2.format(date));
```

You might also want to set a Locale for your second formatter depending on where you live.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.US);
System.out.println(formatter2.format(date));
```

> 12:12:00 PM

Answer (score 1):

Pass the AM/PM in the time

```
Date date = new Date();
String stringDate = "2019-09-13 12:12:00 PM";
SimpleDateFormat formatter6 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
Date date6 = formatter6.parse(stringDate);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(date6));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it the modern way, that is using `java.time`:

```
String stringDate = "2019-09-13 12:12:00";  
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");  
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(stringDate, dtf); 
DateTimeFormatter dtfA = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(datetime.format(dtfA));
// receive the time part and format it
LocalTime timePart = datetime.toLocalTime();
DateTimeFormatter tf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println(timePart.format(tf));
```

This outputs

```
2019-09-13 12:12:00 PM
12:12:00 PM
```

on my system.

> Note that your pattern `String` used for parsing is wrong since **you are not using capital `"H"` for the hours of day, but `"h"` instead. That will definitely not work (correctly)**.

Comment: Try changing the time from 12 to 16 for instance, not exactly the expected output...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Hmm... right, but I think that's due to a bad pattern... I will fix that soon, thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions,

1.

```
Date date = new Date(); 
String stringDate = "2019-09-13 12:12:00 PM";  
SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
```

2.

```
Date date = new Date(); 
String stringDate = "2019-09-13 12:12:00";  
SimpleDateFormat formatter6=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 8 or above then you should definitely use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter` makes it way easier to work with date times.

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
String am = LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter);
String pm = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(2).format(formatter);
System.out.println(am);
System.out.println(pm);
```

Now I am assuming that I run this code during am hours just 2 hours before it changes to pm you can also try out `@Joakim Danielson` answer which should not be dependent on when it is run.

checkout the documentation for [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html)  and [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)